# does it make sense to use spring cloud gateway to implement and enforce a content security policy?

Tags: content-security-policy, spring-cloud-gateway

We use [spring cloud gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) to route requests to various microservices.  Those microservices return a response to spring cloud gateway.  Spring cloud gateway has the opportunity to modify the response before returning to the user / web browser.  Does it make sense to implement a [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) header directive at the gateway level, or does it make more sense to set the header in the other underlying microservices?